# Broadcast receiver not exceuted on application force close

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an application developed for jelly bean, where I schedule an event to be executed in the future using Alarm manager. The scheduled event executes as expected as long as the application runs in the foreground or in the background. But once I force close the application under taskmanager, I am no longer able to receive the broadcast from the alarm manager.

As suggested by various posts and blogs i tried using Intent.Flag_Include_Stopped_Packages. But it was of no use. Including this flag in the intent works only for sendBroadcast(intent). But in case of an alarm manager where pending intent is used,it does not work.

My code to schedule the alarm

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.dummy.intent");  
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),dummyId, intent,                          PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduledAlarm.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

My mainfest

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.androidScheduling.alarmReceiver"                         
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true" 
          android:process=":remote">

       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.dummy.intent"></action>
       </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Can someone please help me out?
I even tried including `android:process = ":remote"` for the receiver in manifest. But even that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not spelled correctly the intent's action name in manifest and programmatically .

**`In pro-grammatically`**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.dummy.intent");
```

**`Manifest file`**-

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.custom.intent"></action>
</intent-filter>
```

`The action name to intent and declared in manifest must require same`.

Hope this helpful to you

Comment: @karan421: If you feel it is correct answer please upvote answer. It is good practice.

Comment: @swapnil am sorry.i made a mistake while posting it on stackoverflow.I edited it now.